# What is a Global Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Global Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Global Words™ | Not Global Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| NET | NUT |
| CASH | COIN |
| HUGE | TINY |
| SOME | NONE |
| CZAR | TSAR |
| SITH | JEDI |
| PASS | PORT |
| PAWS | FLAWS |
| VISIT | SIGHT |
| MAGI | MAGIC |
| TRUST | TRUTH |
| GLIDES | HIDES |
| ECLAIR | PASTRY |
| STREET | ROAD |
| BAGGAGE | BAGGINS |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Global Words™,Not Global Words™
NET,NUT
CASH,COIN
HUGE,TINY
SOME,NONE
CZAR,TSAR
SITH,JEDI
PASS,PORT
PAWS,FLAWS
VISIT,SIGHT
MAGI,MAGIC
TRUST,TRUTH
GLIDES,HIDES
ECLAIR,PASTRY
STREET,ROAD
BAGGAGE,BAGGINS
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Global Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Global Words™.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that a Global Word has the property that

> Each pair of consecutive letters in the word is an officially assigned [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) code for a country or territory

Examples

> **NET** has **NE** (Niger) and **ET** (Ethiopia) 
>  **CASH** has **CA** (Canada), **AS** (American Samoa) and **SH** (Saint Helena) 
>  **HUGE** has **HU** (Hungary), **UG** (Uganda) and **GE** (Georgia) 
>  **SOME** has **SO** (Somalia), **OM** (Oman) and **ME** (Montenegro) 
>  **CZAR** has **CZ** (Czechia), **ZA** (South Africa) and **AR** (Argentina) 
>  **SITH** has **SI** (Slovenia), **IT** (Italy) and **TH** (Thailand) 
>  **PASS** has **PA** (Panama), **AS** (American Samoa) and **SS** (South Sudan) 
>  **PAWS** has **PA** (Panama), **AW** (Aruba) and **WS** (Samoa) 
>  **VISIT** has **VI** (US Virgin Islands), **IS** (Iceland), **SI** (Slovenia) and **IT** (Italy) 
>  **MAGI** has **MA** (Morocco), **AG** (Antigua and Barbuda) and **GI** (Gibraltar) 
>   **BAGGAGE** has **BA** (Bosnia and Herzegovina), **AG** *twice* (Antigua and Barbuda), **GG** (Guernsey), **GA** (Gabon) and **GE** (Georgia)

Comment: Well that was fast. It was tough to come up with a name that wasn't a dead giveaway. 4 hours of work for a 10 minute puzzle :(

Comment: You beat it to me. I was just bolding out all the answers.

Comment: @frabjew Don't be too disheartened. I find it incredibly hard to tell how long it will take for a puzzle to be solved. Often it is being looked at by so many people that the chances are somebody will hit upon something very quickly. For me, the CZAR example stood out immediately and put me on the right track. +1 for ingenuity though, I am always impressed by how people keep inventing new variations on this type of puzzle.

Comment: The funny thing is I thought the lack of uncommon letters (KQXZ) would be too noticeable so I added CZAR as the last one :) Curses!

Comment: Nice job, @frabjrew. That was very creative. :)